# Hibernate Code generation reverse engineering enum data type not support

Tags: hibernate

I have one field enum data type in mysql table, but hibernate reverse process **enum data type converted into string format** in pojo class

I defined **status** column as **enum** type in mysql table, but reverse engineering process it converted into **String** format

```
public class Datasetstatus implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer datasetStatusId;
    private String status;      //enum data type in mysql table

     public Integer getDatasetStatusId() {
        return this.datasetStatusId;
    }

    public void setDatasetStatusId(Integer datasetStatusId) {
        this.datasetStatusId = datasetStatusId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }    
}
```

If any suggestions for solving this problem

Comment: please attach some code !!!

Comment: I have added sample code for your reference , please check